# Which acids are created by the combination of a gas and water?

Tags: acid-base, water

Which acids are created by the combination of a gas and water?  I know that carbonic acid is created by combining carbon dioxide and water, but are there others?  Is there a specific name for this kind of acid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific name for these acids. But I can think of at least 4 more. The gases are $HCl,\ SO_2,\ SO_3,$ and $NO_2$.

Comment: To add to this, I believe all of the hydrogen halides are gases under standard conditions. As far as gaseous compounds that actually react to form acidic products (rather than just dissolving), off the top of my head I can add $\ce{X2}$ and $\ce{COX2}$ (for $\ce{X = F, Cl}$), $\ce{ClO2}$, $\ce{OF2}$. I'm sure there must be others.